# RPi3 Boot loop stuck

Tags: ubuntu

I got a new and I had to deploy my test server from windows vm to rpi3. 
I downloaded the ubuntu 16 rpi3 img, created sd card. Connected to router, ssh and run two simple command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now its stuck on boot, I tried googling but nothing relevant pops up. Here is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/POyG6.jpg

Comment: Did it restart in the middle of something important? It sounds like the SD card was corrupted. This usually happens with an improper shutdown.

Comment: Since i was not getting any answers, I did the process again. Made a clean new SD card. ran sudo update and upgrade after that was done I ran sudo reboot and now we are back to same screen.

Comment: That is strange... Did you a do a manual restart, or did it happen automatically?

Comment: Have you tried using a different SD card?

Comment: @Jacobm001 I will order a new SD card and try again. I will update the question after testing.

Comment: Did you reformat the SD card or just replace the files?

Comment: Well, i got new sd card. Downloaded the fresh image of ubuntu server for rpi3. Burned it on sd card. Ran same two command. Rebooted and got a boot loop. Soo i now switched to raspbian lite and its working fine.@CMalasadas @Jacobm001